# Why is the email arriving empty in my email validation function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have been analyzing this code and testing several things for more than a day and I still haven't been able to resolve the following issue:

"Why is the email arriving empty in my email validation function?"

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FirestoreProvider, FirestoreMutation } from "@react-firebase/firestore";
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import '@firebase/analytics';

const config = {
    ...
};

export default function TextInput(){

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const collectionPath = "leads";
    
    async function Submit(runMutation){
        await runMutation({email});
    }

    function validateEmail(email) {
        const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }

    function ValidateAndSubmit(runMutation){
        if(validateEmail(email)){
            Submit(runMutation);
        }else{
            alert("Please type a valid email!");
        }
    }

    function onKeyPress(key){
        if(key === "Enter"){
            ValidateAndSubmit();
        }
    }

    return <FirestoreProvider {...config} firebase={firebase}>
                <input type="email"
                    placeholder="Type your e-mail to receive early access to the product"
                    style={{width : 500, marginRight : 10}}
                    onKeyPress={event => onKeyPress(event.key)}
                    onChange={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        setEmail(e.target.value)
                    }
                    }/>
                <FirestoreMutation path={collectionPath} type="add">
                    {({ runMutation }) => (
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={_ => ValidateAndSubmit(runMutation)}/>
                    )}
                </FirestoreMutation>
            </FirestoreProvider>
}
```

Can anyone identify where the problem is?

Comment: Did you check for console errors?

Comment: There are no errors on the console.

Comment: On keypress you pass `ValidateAndSubmit()` without parameters but in the function you have `runmutation` param.

Comment: Yes, this will probably make the code not work on the keyboard shortcut part, but I'm not using that part right now, I'm just using the submit button

Comment: How the `{({ runMutation }) => ...` is called?

Comment: It's not called. The running stop at if(validateEmail(email)){ because "" isn't a valid email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230801/discussion-between-marios-nikolaou-and-thallysson-klein).

Answer (score -1):

**{ email }** is not a valid notation.

I would recommend you to write :

```
async function Submit(runMutation){
        await runMutation(email);
}
```

Or

```
async function Submit(runMutation){
 await runMutation({ email : email});
}
```

Comment: It is a completely valid notation and called destructuring assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but email is a string, then if email is a complex string, { email } doesn't work

Comment: It depends on what `runMutation` expects as a parameter. If it is `runMutation(param: string)`, then you are right. If it is `runMutation(param: {email: string})`, the approach is totally fine.